# How can I keep track of state of dynamically added list items in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background**

I'm building an e-commerce site with a fake products API, I have a component which renders a list of products, and a details displaying component. I would like to add some sort of prompt or ideally disable 'Add to cart' buttons in both list item component and details component while item is in the cart.

I'm using React and Context API to pass state (as a learning project), I've tried to add state each item list but then I have no way of passing it to details components, or to cart component so when user clears the cart, buttons go back to normal.

**Potential solutions**

The only solution I came up with is using `indexOf` to test if the item is in the cart once the 'Add to cart' button is clicked and then display an info the the user if it is (not sure how to do it though)
Is there any way to track the state of each induvidual item and then for example change the button to disabled?

**Product component :**

```
const Product = (props) => {
  const CartValue = useCart();
  const DetailValue = useDetail();
  const ModalValue = useModal();

  const {image_link, price, name} = props.product;
  const product = props.product;
 
  // updates cart and opens modal
  const handleCart = () => {
    if(CartValue.cart.indexOf(product)) {
      CartValue.setCart(prev => [...prev, product]);
      ModalValue.setModal({modalItem: product, modalOpen: true});
    } else {
      console.log('lol');
    }
  };

  return (
    <ProductWrapper className='col-9 mx-auto col-md-5 col-lg-3 my-3'>
      <div className="card">
        {/* TO DO Persist to local storage so user can bookmark link directly to Details component, or make fetch request? might take too long TO DO  */}
        <div className="img-container p-4" onClick={() => DetailValue.setDetail(props.product)}>
          <Link to='/details'>
            <img src={image_link} alt="product" className='card-img-top'/>
          </Link>
          {/* add to cart button */}
          <button className="cart-btn" onClick={() =>handleCart()}>
          <i className="fas fa-cart-plus"/>
          </button>
        </div>
        {/* footer */}
        <div className="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
          <p className='align-self-center mb-0'>{name}</p>
          <p className="h5 text-dark font-italic mb-0">
            <span className='mr-1'>${price}</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ProductWrapper>
  )
}
```

**Details component:**

```
const Details = () => {

  const CartValue = useCart();
  const DetailValue = useDetail();

  const {name, description, price, brand, image_link, rating} = DetailValue.detail;

  return (
    <div className="container py-5">
      {/* product title */}
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-10 mx-auto text-center text-slanted text-orange my5">
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* end title */}
      {/* product info */}
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 my-3">
          <img src={image_link} className='img-fluid w-100' alt={name}/>
        </div>
        <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 my-3 text-capitalize">
          <p className='h4'>{name}</p>
          <div className='text-muted mt-3 mb-2'>
            <p>brand: <span className='text-uppercase'>{brand}</span></p>
            <p>rating: <span>{rating}</span></p>
          </div>
          <p className="h4 text-orange">
            <strong>
              price: <span>$</span>{price}
            </strong>
          </p>
          <p className=" font-weight-bold mt-3 mb-0">
            product description:
          </p>
          <p className="lead">
            {description}
          </p>
          <div>
            <Link to='/'>
              <ButtonContainer>
                Back to products
              </ButtonContainer>
            </Link>
            <ButtonContainer onClick={() => addToCart(CartValue, DetailValue.detail)}>
              Add To Cart
            </ButtonContainer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**App structure:**

```
<Route exact path="/" component={ProductList}/>
<Route path="/details" component={Details} />
<Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
<Route path="/about" component={About} />
<Route path="/location" component={Location} />
```

**State and hook placed in a separate file**

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';

// creating contexts for global state
const ModalContext = createContext();
const DetailContext = createContext();
const CartContext = createContext();
// end of creating contexts

// custom hooks to access each state
export const useModal = () => {
  return useContext(ModalContext);
}

export const useDetail = () => {
  return useContext(DetailContext);
}

export const useCart = () => {
  return useContext(CartContext);
}
// end of custom hooks

// Add to cart helper function
export const addToCart = (cart, item, modal) => {
  const element = item;
  const updateCart = () => cart.setCart(prev => Array.from(new Set([...prev, element])));

  if(!modal){
    updateCart();
  } else {
    updateCart();
    modal.setModal({modalItem: element, modalOpen: true});
  }
};

// GLOBAL STATE and wrapper for each state.
export const GlobalState = ({ children }) => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState({modalItem: {}, modalOpen: false});
  const [detail, setDetail] = useState({});
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider value={{modal,setModal}}>
      <DetailContext.Provider value={{detail, setDetail}}>
        <CartContext.Provider value={{cart, setCart}}>
          {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
      </DetailContext.Provider>
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Where is `addToCart` defined and what does it do?

Comment: I'd need more information about how your Contexts are set up to answer this question correctly.  Your update functions seem like they could be okay, but I'm suspecting that you're not holding the state in a way that React will listen to correctly.  Please include a bit more about how the Contexts are initiated and how their values are being stored.

Comment: Edited post to add more info, includes `addToCart` function, which is an old, placeholder version.